# I want to load a webpage on login page .I've created a log-in page with a static ID and password.

Tags: iphone

I want to create a *login page* that will take login details of user and redirect him to the main page. i dont know how can i do that . plz help me.

```
 if([username isEqualToString:@"aa"] && [password isEqualToString:@"aa"])
    {
        Supportingwv *swv = [[Supportingwv alloc]initWithNibName:@"supportingwv"bundle:nil];
        NSString *urlstring = @"www.google.com";
        [ swv setUrlString : urlstring];
        [self.view addSubview:swv.view];
    }
    else
    {        
        UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"invalid authentication" message:@"username & password doesnot match" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert show];
    }
```

Comment: Some more information on your question (other than your title) would be good if you want people to help you

Comment: actually i m trying to create a web page login application but it is not working properly.only if{.. } area is creating the prob. every time it goes crash when i enter the right ID and password but else{..} condition is working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess Supportingwv is a UIWebView, so you have to load the request [loadRequest method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) :

```
[swv loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL urlWithString:urlString]]];
```

But without more explanation we can't help you.

EDIT :

If you want to load a page just use the following :

```
if([username isEqualToString:@"aa"] && [password isEqualToString:@"aa"])
{
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[URL urlWithString:@"www.google.com"]]];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
}
else
{        
    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"invalid authentication" message:@"username & password doesnot match" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

This code creates a webview with the URL you want (here it's www.google.com) and it add and show the webview to the current controller.

Comment: thnk u so much Ashbay but this is code is not working too.. :'(

Comment: thnk u for ur support buddy// :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.google.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [swv loadRequest:requestObj];
    [self.view addSubview:swv.view]; 
    [swv release];
```

Comment: 'release' is not available:not available in automatic reference counting mode

Comment: No visible @interface for 'Supportingwv' declares the selector 'loadRequest:'

Answer (score 0):

You should check now in this delegate of webview

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

NSString *urlString = request.URL.absoluteString;
//Check the username or password in urlString with the help of RegularExpression


//or check user has succssfully login or not
   }
```